# Best VSLAM Algorithm for Outdoor Navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am building an outdoor robot and would like to know what is the most suitable algorithm of visual SLAM for outdoor robot navigation using ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391776/best-vslam-algorithm-for-outdoor-navigation/) by [Nabil Miri](https://answers.ros.org/users/88977/nabil-miri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not usually about advertising my papers in this venue, but I think some work here could give you some good context https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.07589 "A Comparison of Modern General-Purpose Visual SLAM Approaches". The aim of the paper was comparing existing openly available VSLAM systems for practical service robot application.

While we do not specifically focus on "Outdoor" you can see extensive discussions about the weaknesses and strengths of different methods given access to different hardware in various service environments (including outdoors as an important subsection).

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nabil Miri](https://answers.ros.org/users/88977/nabil-miri/) on 2021-12-03**:
This paper is really informative, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not all inclusive answer because the subject it's a very broad and well researched.
Excluding hardware demands as this another broad subject, I will just give you some guidance to start your research.

For example ORB_SLAM2 is well established and popular ROS community.

> ORB_SLAM2:  ROS implementation of the
> ORB-SLAM2 real-time SLAM library for
> Monocular, Stereo and RGB-D cameras
> that computes the camera trajectory
> and a sparse 3D reconstruction (in the
> stereo and RGB-D case with true
> scale). It is able to detect loops and
> relocalize the camera in real time.

**Reference**: https://github.com/appliedAI-Initiative/orb_slam_2_ros

To compare the performance against others, you can read ORB-SLAM: a Versatile and Accurate Monocular SLAM System goes in depth about the particulars of benefits, benchmarks and results
[http://webdiis.unizar.es/~raulmur/MurMontielTardosTRO15.pdf](http://webdiis.unizar.es/%7Eraulmur/MurMontielTardosTRO15.pdf)

If you visit **KITTI Vision Benchmark Suite**:
You will find hundreds of implementations, with papers and many algorithms that optimize for particular requirements.
http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_odometry.php

From this you can use KITTI dataset to test your algorithm and compare performance to others as well.
All these implementations can be integrated with ROS.

Other implementation to consider is Open VSLAM: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.01122.pdf

And more recent and extremely promising ORB_SLAM3: https://github.com/UZ-SLAMLab/ORB_SLAM3

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nabil Miri](https://answers.ros.org/users/88977/nabil-miri/) on 2021-12-03**:
Thanks for this info